# Another RewriteRule wondering

Tags: .htaccess, mod-rewrite, url-rewriting, directory, symfony

In my Apache server I want to make this redirection : everything that comes in this directory (this is not the server root) that is not a file should be passed as arguments to the real_location/index.php front controller (this is a Symfony2 project).

```
<IfModule mod_rewrite.c>
    RewriteEngine On

    RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
    RewriteRule ./(.*)    ./real_location/index.php/$1 [QSA,L]
</IfModule>
```

If someone gets a clue I am most interested.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

try this:

```
<IfModule mod_rewrite.c>
    RewriteEngine On

    RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
    RewriteRule ^(.*)$ real_location/index.php [QSA,L]
</IfModule>
```

It should work ! (and $_GET is given)

Cheers

Comment: It's working perfectly on my server ! Are you sure that mod rewrite is enabled on your apache server ? (Command line to activate it: a2enmod rewrite, or check it in conf if you're on wamp)

Comment: I have tried your solution and it works. Actually my problem is a bit different : I want to redirect all `af/foo` to `af/bar/index.php/foo`.

Comment: I have tried and your solution works properly with regular, simple files. But I have a Symfony2 redirection to /login that does not work, I don't understand why.

Comment: I don't understand what you want to do :o In your previous comment, are you speaking about namespace ? Can you give me the resulting login URL (and other usefull information that you think to debug) ?

Comment: In fact, when I go to `/af`, apache redirects to `/af/index.php`, then symfony2 redirects to `/af/login` and I get a 404. When the logical redirection is done we should get `/af/index.php/login`.